# tighten security features of an existing SQL Server 2008 R2 Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need to tighten the security of an existing SQL Server 2008 R2 by disabling certain Instance level configuration options.  For example, CLR, Trustworthy, xp_dirtree, xp_regread etc.

How can I check whether disabling these will affect any of my applications/processes.

This is a production server.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How to check? Take a full backup of master, model, msdb, and all user databases, and then restore to a ***test*** server. Make your changes and retest all of the apps, pointing connection strings to the test server. There really isn't much more to it than that. It's just a long, manual process depending on how many apps are using the database(s) on the server.